# Multivariable Regression on correlated / collinear variables

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, multicollinearity, controlling-for-a-variable, multivariable

Let us consider a variable $Y$ on which we want to apply a multivariable linear regression on the variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are collinear by construction, with $X_1=ab$ and $X_2=bc$, in which $a$,$b$, and $c$ are measurable quantities for which we acquired observational data.

The objective is to evaluate the correlation between $Y$ and $X_1$ while controlling for $X_2$, and vice-versa.

Is there a a more adequate way of testing for correlation on one variable while simultaneously controlling for another variable? Is it legit to perform such an analysis, even in the presence of collinearity? 
Note that $X_1$ and $X_2$, while related, are different quantities that are expected to be correlated with $Y$ for different reasons (akin to density and surface area, and its relation with volume, for instance).

Comment: For each observation, you have measurements $a_i$, $b_i$, and $c_i$? And those measurements vary across observations? Correct?

Comment: Correct and Correct. Just not to confuse the index $i$ with that of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: There is no exact linear relationship $X_1$ and $X_2$, and a regression of $Y$ on $X_1$ and $X_2$ wouldn't suffer perfect multicollinearity. There would be multicollinearity if $a$ and $c$ were constants or had almost no variation in the data (i.e. then you would have $X_1 = \frac{a}{c} X_2$.

Comment: I agree; but do you think the analysis procedure is the most adequate? Or would you suggest a different approach to measure correlation while controling for the other variable?

Comment: I don't know because I don't know your problem. All I can say is that regressing on $y$ on $x_{1,i} = a_i b_i$ and $x_{2,i} = b_i c_i$ should be fine from a multicollinearity standpoint as long as something degenerate isn't going on (eg. like $a_i = c_i$ etc...). You can also figure out multi-collinearity from the logic of your problem: eg. regressing on the temperature in fahrenheit and the temperature in celsius and a constant would suffer mutlicollinearity. You can also check the correlation isn't too high between $x_1$ and $x_2$.